# Firebug behavior when selecting an item from dropdown-list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, firebug

I have a dropdownlist which when user selects an item from it, it renders the partial with relevant data. But if user changes the selection of ddl then the previously rendered content should be replaced with the current content.

Following is the code

Script

```
<script>
        var prev;
        $(document).on('focus', '.class03', function () {
            prev = $(this).val();
        }).on('change', '.class03', function () {
            if (prev != "") {
                $('.cmpCls').last().remove();
                alert(prev);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ComponentDts", "InquiryOrder")', // dont hard code your url's
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { DesignCdId: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#cmpDts').append(data);
                    }
                }); 
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ComponentDts", "InquiryOrder")', // dont hard code your url's
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { DesignCdId: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#cmpDts').append(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        </script>
```

Div to append rendered Partial View

```
<div id="cmpDts">

</div>
```

Here what confuses me is when i use firebug, the script works fine replacing the previously rendered content in 'cmpDts' div when user changes the selection of dropdownlist.

But when i run the application without firebug and when user changes the selection of ddl, instead of replacing the previous content in div, it keeps on adding to the div without removing previous content.

I think without firebug, everytime it comes to `else` part no matter `prev` has a value or not. I could recognize it beacause `alert` not get fired without firebug here. Im confused with this behavior. All help appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: How i got that worked(I know this might not be the correct approach but with the restricted time i had to stick with this)

```
<script>
        var prev;
        $(document).on('focus', '.class03', function () {
            prev = $(this).val();
        }).on('change', '.class03', function () {
            if (prev != "") {
                //$('.cmpCls').last().remove();
                alert("If");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ComponentDts", "InquiryOrder")', // dont hard code your url's
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { DesignCdId: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.cmpCls').last().replaceWith(data);
                    }
                }); 
            }
            else {
                alert("Else");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ComponentDts", "InquiryOrder")', // dont hard code your url's
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { DesignCdId: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(".class03 option[value='']").remove() ;
                        $('#cmpDts').append(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: What happens if you press Ctrl + F5 to reload the page and then try it again? It might be the case that your browser is using the cached version without firebug on.

Comment: @L Ja, Thanks for replying. Yes i did that. But still keeps on adding to the div. Do you think the way i have written the script is correct?

Comment: Oh, you want it to replace the content? In that case, use `.html()` instead of     `.append()`. .`append()` pastes the new value behind the current value. `.html()` replaces it.

Comment: @L Ja, Yes i used that also. Then it get's replaced. But the problem is it never comes to `if` part. `Alert` doesn't fire. There are other dropdowns in the view and for those ddls, new content should get added to the end of previous content. But for a particular dropdown it should be a replace. Any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: Is `.class03` the class that should replace it, and for example `.class01` and `.class02` append?

Comment: @L Ja, `class01 `,`class02 ` are not that much relevant here. Only `class03`. Every ddl has this same class. But for a particular ddl there should be only one content(replace for different selections). For seperate ddls relevent content should be added to div.

Comment: I'll create an answer to see if I can help you out further.

Comment: @L Ja, Ok thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Don't use `$('#cmpDts').append(data);` which **appends** the html. Use ` `$('#cmpDts').html(data);` which replaces the html.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thanks for replying :) Yes it solved the initial problem. But there are other ddls in view(which i didn't mentioned in my question). that renders this partial view and for those ddls data related to selected item should get appended after the previous content. But for a single ddl change it should be a replace. The issue is with `append` and `html` as you said. But i couldn't solved it yet. Pls help?

Comment: @Isuru, You need to give a bit more detail on what the logic is for either appending or replacing. And show the html for a few of the dropdownlists your referring to (in particular any `class` or `id` attributes)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, With the restricted time i had, i changed my script a bit and got that worked. I edited my question so that you can see what i have done. Anyways thank for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

You first of all need to wait for your document to be ready by using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Now, you want to check if something in .class03 changed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var prev;
    $(".class03").focus(function(){ prev = $(this).val(); });

    $(".class03").change(function(){
        if (prev !== "") { $('.cmpCls').last().remove(); }
            alert(prev);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ComponentDts", "InquiryOrder")', // dont hard code your url's
                type: "GET",
                data: { DesignCdId: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#cmpDts').append(data);
                }
            }); 
    });
});
```

Try this.

**Edit: removed double code**

Comment: @L Ja, Thanks for the answer. Your earlier suggestion to use `html` is correct. It solved the initial problem. But now for other ddls also it started to replace without adding when i use `html`. And also i suppose because im dynamically generating this content i have to use `on` and bind the event with an already  existing div which i have already done in my script.

Comment: In that case, you need to have a check if the dropdown is one that should append or replace. Maybe add data-function="html" to the html one, then data-function="append" to the append ones. On your succes check `if($(this).attr("data-function") === "html") { $("#cmpDts").html(data) } else if($this.attr("data-function") === "append") { $("#cmpDts").append(data); }`

Comment: Ok i'll try that. Thank you!

Comment: @L Ja, Sorry for the late reply. Yes i got that worked. Considering your earlier suggestions and with the restricted time i had, i changed my script a little and got that worked. I edited my question so you can see what i did. Anyway thanks for helping me :)